# GIT recursive merge commit vs. squash merge commit?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Aren't **recursive** merge commits and squash merge commits the same thing? **This question has nothing to do with fast-foward scenarios or merge operations at all**. Suppose we have a branch named "**feature**" with commits named A, B, and C. Also a branch named **main** exists with commits 1 and 2, where 1 actually branches off into the feature branch. We want to merge this "**feature**" branch onto the "**main**" branch through a recursive merge operation. As a result of the recursive merge operation, a new merge-commit will be generated at the end of the main branch that implements the total changes made by commits A, B, and C. How is this any different than a squashed merge commit? More specifically the "--squash" parameter? When might I, a company, or a workflow prefer squash or recursive merge commits?

Comment: Does this question concern the "recursive merge" strategy that Git offers?

Comment: Yes, I was asking about a merge commit via recursive strategy as compared to the same operation with the --squash flag passed. Since they both result in one commit. @j6t

Comment: There are lots of referencers out there for 'squash or merge', [like this one](https://blog.mergify.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-merge-commit-a-squash/), but not on stackoverflow as the choice between one or the other is largely subjective. `How is this any different than a squashed merge commit` please add the start and resultant states for both of these merge options to the question to clarify.

Comment: `When might I, a company, or a workflow prefer squash or recursive merge commits?` can you also please edit the question to clarify what this means (how can a person be a company, and how does it affect things one way or another if 'you' are?) - it doesn't mean anything to me and I can guess it does't mean much to other readers either.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is:

- The *recursive* aspect of the merge is how the merge operation arrives at the result, but is not about what you do with the result.
- `--squash`, OTOH, is about what to do with the merge result. In particular, it creates a new commit without a second parent. If you omit `--squash` a merge commit (with two parents) is created.

The case that you illustrate, a feature that evolves in a linear history of commits, does not need a recursive merge strategy. The recursive aspect comes into play when you have a history that contains criss-cross merges.

```
--r--o--F--o    <-- main
   \   /
     x          <-- lines cross (not a commit)
   /   \
--f--o--R--o    <-- feature
```

At one point, a half-completed feature was merged into `main` (resulting in `F`), at another point, an old state of `main`, say, a tagged release, was merged into `feature`, resulting in `R`.

When the two branches are now merged, the *recursive* strategy is used, because the two branches have two merge bases, `r` and `f`. The merge proceeds by constructing a virtual tree by merging `r` and `f`, and then it uses that tree as the merge base of the final merge. Think of it as being in the place where the lines cross, `x`.

Comment: Ok, so the only real difference between a recursive merge commit and a squash merge commit is that the recursive merge commit will have two parents and a squash will have one. Referring back to the example in my question, feature has commits A B and C. Now assume that main has commits 1 and 2, where 1 is where feature branches off from. When might I, a company, or a workflow prefer a recursive merge or squash? At the end of the day, recursive merge and squash both generate a single commit. Is this dependent on whether we are updating feature as compared to fully pushing it to main?    @j6t

Comment: As said in matt's answer and in this: squash and recursive are independent concepts, not exclusive ones. If you say `git merge`, you automatically choose recursive merge strategy. If you say `git merge --squash`, you choose *also* recursive merge strategy.  Whether or not you say `--squash` only has the effect of whether you generate a commit with one or with two parents. In the example you give in the comment, you only want to choose whether the commit has one or two parents. I will never suggest a workflow that uses squash merges regularly, in particular not in a professional setting.

Answer (score 2):

These are two unrelated orthogonal settings. A merge is either recursive or not, and it is either squash or not. So you could have

- Squash and recursive
- Squash and not recursive
- Not squash and recursive
- Not squash and not recursive

The thing to understand is this: A merge creates a new commit. Given that fact:

- `recursive` is about the *logic* by which that commit is created. It modifies the normal merge logic; it isn't a modification you would normally have any need to make, and if you did, you might have a lot more to think about in order to get a "right" answer, so I would suggest not using it.
- As to the *nature* of the resulting commit, a normal merge creates a merge commit, but a squash merge does not (a squash merge is not a merge). Whether you would use this is sort of business decision; I've worked in situations where we were required to merge this way, but in my opinion this is a bad thing to do, as you lose history and, if your branch is long-lived, you risk a big increase in merge conflicts. People who think that squash merges make the history "cleaner" are, in my opinion, just mistake about what "clean" is.

Comment: On how normal merge logic works, as well as a discussion of squash merges and why they are potentially bad, especially in conjunction with long-lived branches, see my article https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/